# Android Bitmap causing memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have tried all the solutions that I could find and none of them help. Most of them talk about recycling the bitmap which isn't an option for me. My app is doing some image processing in a separate thread from the UI and then I use paint to draw a solid circle at a location that my image processing algorithm returns. Here is my code -

```
    private Runnable runNetwork = new Runnable() 
  {
    public void run() 
    {
        if(!destroyFlag)
        {
            bProcessing = true;         

            start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            locations = callTorch(torchState, PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight, FrameData,networkLoop); 
            stop = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            wholeLoop = (float) ((stop-start)*0.001);
            fps = 1/wholeLoop;
            start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

            if(locations[0] != 0)
            {
                bitmap.eraseColor(0);
                for(int i = 0; i < locations.length; i+=4)
                {
                    if(locations[i+2] != 0)
                    {
                        mCanvas.drawCircle(locations[i], locations[i+1], 10, p);
                        mCanvas.drawText("Face", locations[i], locations[i+1]+15, p);

                    }
                }
            }
            else
                bitmap.eraseColor(0);

            MycameraClass.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            stop = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            displayLoop = (float) ((stop-start) * 0.001);

            networkPercentage = (networkLoop/wholeLoop)*100;

            CameraActivity.detailsText.setText("****Profiling information****\n" + "Time for network = " + networkLoop + " s\nTime for whole loop = " +
                        wholeLoop + " s\nNetwork takes " + networkPercentage + "% of computation time" + "\nTime for display = " + displayLoop + "s \nFrame rate =" + fps);

            bProcessing = false;
        }
    }
  };
```

I reuse the same bitmap to draw on so I cannot recycle it. Is there any reason this should cause a memory leak? It is a pretty bad one too. My app can barely run half a minute before it crashes.

**EDIT**: More code fragments relavent to Bitmap creation

```
 public class CameraClass implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback
 {
    private Camera mCamera = null;
private ImageView MycameraClass = null;
    public Bitmap bitmap = null;
private int[] pixels = null;
private byte[] FrameData = null;
private int imageFormat;
private int PreviewSizeWidth;
private int PreviewSizeHeight;
private boolean bProcessing = false;
float start, stop, networkLoop, wholeLoop, fps, displayLoop, networkPercentage = 0;
Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
public long torchState = 0;
private boolean destroyFlag = false;
Paint p = new Paint();
Canvas mCanvas;
int[] locations;

public CameraClass(int PreviewlayoutWidth, int PreviewlayoutHeight, ImageView cameraClass)
{
    PreviewSizeWidth = PreviewlayoutWidth;
    PreviewSizeHeight = PreviewlayoutHeight;
    MycameraClass = cameraClass;
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1280, 768, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    p.setStrokeWidth((float)15.0);
    p.setTextSize(100);
}
```

Above is the class that creates the bitmap. This class is called from the Activity shown below -

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity
{

private FrameLayout mainLayout;
private ImageView MyCameraClass = null;
private CameraClass camPreview;
private int PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight;
static AssetManager assetManager;
static TextView detailsText;
Button back;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  

    assetManager = getAssets();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(buttonHandler);

    detailsText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.details);

    MyCameraClass = new ImageView(this);

    SurfaceView camView = new SurfaceView(this);
    SurfaceHolder camHolder = camView.getHolder();

    PreviewSizeWidth = MainActivity.width;
    PreviewSizeHeight = MainActivity.height;

    camPreview = new CameraClass(PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight, MyCameraClass);
    camHolder.addCallback(camPreview);

    camHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
    mainLayout.addView(camView, new LayoutParams(1280, 768));
    mainLayout.addView(MyCameraClass, new LayoutParams(1280, 768));

}
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but it's a relatively new video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8

Comment: Have You tried to capture memory profile (http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)? If it's the bitmap it would be clearly visible in there.

Comment: @sandrstar Yes I have. MAT tells me that one instance of bitmap is using over 40% memory in my code. I have another more detailed post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386602/identifying-memory-leak-with-mat) regarding that which I did not get a response to so had to double post. Bitmaps also appear in the DDMS' allocation tracker all over the place. Finally, the DDMS' pie chart for memory usage shrinks at a fast rate and only a large bitmap that allocates 24bits of 1280x768 images can eat up memory that fast (I have nothing else that allocates arrays larger than 10 or 12 ints).

Comment: can you please post the code where you are opening the bitmap, Had the same issue, and Hope that I can help you.

Comment: @Tarek Done. I added all that I could think of relevant to the bitmap. If it is difficult to read, I can trim it down. Thanks.

Comment: `more detailed post here regarding that which I did not get a response to so had to double post.`  - that's not how SO works.

Comment: @Simon Thanks for your insight. I am not sure if you checked the second post but while it is a post about the same problem, it is asking for help on a different topic. That post is asking for help with the memory analyzer tool. I do not care about the downvote (if it indeed was you) but something constructive on my problem would help me with my project and help me learn.

Comment: try changing
**bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1280, 768, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);**
to
**bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1280, 768, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);**

Comment: That didn't work. I'm not sure why it would either. The RGB_565 colorspace is simply half in size of the ARGB_8888 colorspace. Sure enough, the memory grew at a smaller pace but it grew nonetheless. Thanks for your help though...